# ASP.NET Identity Login > Logout > Login doesnt work (result = success)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I would like to build a Website where I can setup multiple companies.
Each company should have its own database for its actual business-data and a database for its own identity framework settings.

To do this I've a simple list with companies that refer to different databases like described before.

Signing up users in them works, since I just need to store the applicationUserManagers within the same company object when theyre created.

But when I now do this: Login a user, log him out afterwards and then login again, even though this in the login function:

```
var result = await ic.applicationSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

returns "success", the user isnt logged in and I am send to the login page again.

Please tell me what else I need to consider.

Comment: Are you using roles? If the user is logged in but tries to access a page that is restricted to only members of a certain role, they will be redirected to the login page again

Comment: This user has the role for accessing the dashboard page, where he is redirected to when he first logged in.

                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl); //returnUrl is "/" here so he goes to the main index page

Answer (score 0):

Okay I failed there.

When creating the applicationUserManager when logging in, I did this (among other things):

```
ic = new IdentityConfig();
ic.applicationSignInManager = new ApplicationSignInManager(ic.applicationUserManager, HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
[...]
```

I found out that this OwinContext fetched here from the HttpContext relates to the signing in (obviously it has to do with Authentication). But instead of executing this line each and every single time a user logs in, I stored the resulting IdentityConfig (Wich associates the ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationSignInManager with a Company) in a List also and reused it for every login that comes after that. (Actually this is just me trying to be performant by keeping little data that doesnt actually change all the time on the server application instead of pulling it all the time from the db)

So after the first user logged in, the same owincontext was being used each time and this somehow doesnt work internally.

The solution was to just dont store this OwinContext and creating it from scratch each time.